# Append different n-length elements to a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, append

I was attempting to append elements to a vector coming out of a for loop, and noticed a `more elements supplied than there are to replace` error that kept popping up. Upon some investigating, I noticed that this was primarily due to the fact that the first appended element was of length 1, and the second was of length greater than 1. Example code below.

My question is how best to handle for these moments?

Example code :

```
some_list[[1]] = 1
some_list[[2]] = 1:10
some_list[[3]] = 20:30

output = c()
for (i in 1:lenth(some_list)){
    output[[i]] = some_list[i] * 10}
```

Comment: The issue with your code is the one time you use `[` instead of `[[`. If you try`output[[i]] = some_list[[i]] * 10` it should work fine.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Also I noticed that if you run `some_list = c(); some_list[[1]] = 1; some_list[[2]] = 1:10` you get the same error.

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: I'd expect the output to be `output[[1]] = 10; output[[2]] = c(10, 20, 30, ...)`

Comment: what's wrong with @李哲源 's solution. It gives your expected output `lapply(some_list, "*", 10)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that output is defined as a character vector and not a list. Try this instead:

```
some_list = list()
some_list[[1]] = 1
some_list[[2]] = 1:10
some_list[[3]] = 20:30

output = list()  # output should be a list
for (i in 1:length(some_list)){
    output[[i]] = some_list[[i]] * 10}
```